# How to install larger memory sd card

Tags: samsung

I have a samsung galaxy prime and have just bought a 64 g memory card as the 8 g was not big enough. According to the youtube video i must insert the new card on top of my sim card. It slots in fine, is recognised on the settings as more memory, but still saying storage space running out. What else must i do please.

Answer (score 4):

> but still saying storage space running out

this probably refers to the internal memory of your device. Apps are by default stored on the internal memory. What you can do to increase the available space on your internal memory is the following:

1. Move all media files (your photos/ music / videos) to your external SD-Card. You can use a file explorer to do so (cut and paste).
2. -If available- move app data to your SD card - to do this go into your settings, search "applications / application manager" and look for each app if you can move it to the SD card

Answer (score 1):

The usual basic solutions: clear your cache (and do it frequently), Uninstall unnecessary apps, moving apps to sd card (if available).

Apart from these, what I do is manually move some of the App's data folders in internal storage (Android/data and Android/obb), to external SD card (usually huge games that are taking lot of space), and move them internal storage only when I want to play them. Move them back later.